# how to split a string with two or more pattern in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I Want to split a String in php to Array that I have two or more separators in it.

```
$string = "[Java , Android , Kotlin]";
```

I need :

```
 $mArray[0] = "Java";

 $mArray[1] = "Android";

 $mArray[2] = "Kotlin";
```

but when I use

```
 $mArray = explode(',' , $string);
```

it return me :

```
 $mArray[0] = "[Java";

 $mArray[1] = "Android";

 $mArray[2] = "Kotlin]";
```

thank you for your answer.

Comment: How you get this string ? Why not store data in such a way that it can easily used after ?

Comment: I get it from Android Java. it's an Array that converted to String

Comment: Remove first and last character before explode?

Comment: Pretty sure Android Java will have JSON-capabilities to convert your array into a format that can be read by something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either fix (remove [ and ]) the string before exploding or loop over it after.

```
<?php
$string = "[Java , Android , Kotlin]";

// remove [ ] and replace space,space with just ,
$string = str_replace(['[', ']', ' , '], [null, null, ','], $string);

$array = explode(',', $string);

print_r($array);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Java
    [1] => Android
    [2] => Kotlin
)
*/
```

Or like the following, if the string is guaranteed to have `space,space`.

```
<?php
$string = "[Java , Android , Kotlin]";

$string = str_replace(['[', ']'], '', $string);

$array = explode(' , ', $string);

print_r($array);
```

Or fix after exploding, either by a foreach or [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) etc.

```
<?php
$string = "[Java , Android , Kotlin]";

$array = explode(',', $string);

array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = trim($value, '[] ');
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: I used this $string = str_replace('[',"",$string);
$string = str_replace(']',"",$string); instead of $string = str_replace(['[', ']'], '', $string);

Comment: That's fine but you don't need to call it twice, you can pass an array like above.

Comment: I did that way but it catches Error in my HostServices

Comment: I don't know what that means, if your still having issues, please update your question with the current code your using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the string before explode :

```
<?php 

$string = "[Java , Android , Kotlin]";
$string=str_replace(["[","]"],["",""],$string);
$mArray=explode(',',$string);
print($mArray[0]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)?

```
$string = "[Java , Android , Kotlin]";
$mArray = preg_split('/\[|\]|\h*,\h*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($mArray);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Java
    [1] => Android
    [2] => Kotlin
)
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
    \[          : open bracket
  |             : OR
    \]          : close bracket
  |             : OR
    \h*,\h*     : a comma between 0 or more horizontal spaces
/               : regex delimiter
```